# As "postagens" perdem/ganham votos quando um usuário é removido?

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Como já foi muito perguntando e acho que a maioria já entende, é que os usuários que solicitam para terem suas contas deletadas ocasionam a alteração de reputação para outros usuários os quais receberam *downvotes* e *upvotes* destes usuários removidos:

- [https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=usuário+removido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=usu%C3%A1rio+removido)

Mas fiquei com uma dúvida, por exemplo tive a perda de 10 pontos pela remoção da conta de um usuário:

> [image: usuário removido]

No entanto **não** me é exibido qual postagem foi alterado, então presumi que na verdade a pergunta não perde o *upvote* ou *downvote*, apenas eu perco o *score*, mas o *upvote* continua na pergunta, como nesta *altura do campeonato* eu não me importo mais com score pessoal, mas sim com os votos para as postagens isoladas.

**Acaso** eu esteja enganado e a postagem perde upvotes quando um usuário é removido, gostaria de saber o porque não posso saber qual postagem teve esta perda.

Comment: Questionei algo parecido [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5628/28595) e não obtive resposta :/

Comment: @Articuno então presumo que as postagens não perdem ups/downs quando o usuário é removido, apenas o score é perdido, eu sempre entendi que era isto, mas não estou certo tão certo agora disto.

Comment: Mas se perder só o score sem os downs/ups os dados ficariam inconsistentes, nao?

Comment: O score não esta diretamente ligado com o sistema de votos, tanto que você pode ganhar +100 por associação de comunidades, quando você é ativo em outro site SE você ganha +100 de graça de incentivo, outro exemplo são as recompensas e edições que geram score pra ti.

Comment: Eu perdi 135 nessa brincadeira de exclusão da conta, mas 100 desses foi pela exclusão de uma pergunta. Quando o usuário é excluído, suas perguntas também são removidas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss as perguntas e respostas não são removidas, pode notar no site que tem muitas postagens o qual o AP não tem link para o perfil, o nome fica algo como `userXXXXX`, mas não são "linkaveis"

Comment: O mesmo aconteceu comigo hoje, na aba reputação tem [esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)

Comment: Do link: "Como resultado, todos os seus votos foram removidos e a reputação que você ganhou ou perdeu foi desfeita"

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado os pontos até creio, mas os votos para as publicações creio que não, tem algunas instruções *"erradas"* nas páginas de Help, mesmo no em inglês aonde confundem votos com score e vice-versa.